# Converting on-screen coordinates to array grid coordinates

Tags: c, arrays, coordinates

I'm using ANSI C and looking to convert on-screen borland graphics coordinates i.e. (35,134) to a grid coordinate of (0,0). My grid creation function is as follows:

```
void createGrid(int ***a, int m, int n)
{
    int i,j,color=0;

    *a=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);    //reserves memory for n

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){   //external loop
        *(*a+i)=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);    //reserves memory for m
    if(a){
         for(j=0;j<m;j++){ //internal loop
            *(*(*a+i)+j)=color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is a dynamic grid and I have been unable to find the correct conversion method. All I've been able to find is a conversion method from array(0,1) to a single index. At this time, I'm working with a grid size of 30X30. My mouse follows on-screen coordinates and I need those coordinates to be converted to the grid position, so a color can be stored and read from such a position.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `sizeof(int)` be `sizeof(int*)`? And please try to avoid being a [3-star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer). Moreover (although here width = height = 30) there is no way tell from the parameter names `m` and `n` which is which.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: m=30, n=30 each cell's size is 10 units. I figured out x to be (index*cell size)+32 where 32 is the first x in the coordinate (32, 131) and (2*10)+32=52. 52 is the grid-x coordinate for (2,0). . Unfortunately, I have been unable to figure out the formula for y.

Comment: @Weather-Vane, you're absolutely right! Thanks for pointing that out in regard to int*. I don't want to be a 3-star programmer, but I'm following my professor's wishes...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a lot of reading and exploring, I found the answer to this dilemma is taking the (coordinate-number of spaces after 0)/size of the cell. In the case of my previous formula, it's (52-32)/10=2. This formula works for both, x and y coordinates to convert them into i & j indexes for a two-dimensional array.